# What is the Sharia ruling on working in a bank?

Tags: halal-haram, riba, work, banking

Nowadays, lot of students look for getting a job in banks. What is the Islamic view if a person gets a job in bank?

Answer (score 10):

It depends. If the bank doesn't deal with Riba (interest), it is absolutely permissible for him to work there.

However, it is not permissible (according to majority of the Sunni scholars) for a Muslim to work in a bank that deals with Riba, even if the job that they are appointed to do is not related to the Riba-based dealings. This is because they would be assisting those who work with Riba and cooperating with them.

Allah (Exalted be He) says:

> ...but do not help one another in sin and transgression. [**[Sur'ah Al-Maidah 5:2]**](http://quran.com/5/2)

In fact, there are rulings which even forbid you from working as a driver there.

Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen (may Allaah have mercy on him) was asked: **is it permissible to work for a riba-based organization as a driver or guard?**

He replied:

> It is not permissible to work for a riba-based organization even if
>   you are a driver or a guard, because accepting employment with a
>   riba-based organization implies that you approve of them, as whoever
>   denounces something could not work to serve its interests. If he works
>   to serve its interests, he must approve of it, and the one who
>   approves of something haraam has a share in its sin. With regard to
>   those who are directly involved in writing down transactions,
>   transferring money, depositing money, etc, are undoubtedly dealing
>   directly with something that is haraam. It was proven from the hadeeth
>   of Jabir (may Allaah be pleased with him) that **the Messenger of Allaah
>   (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) cursed the one who
>   consumes riba, the one who pays it, the one who writes it down and the
>   two who witness it, and he said, “They are all the same.”**

From Fataawa (religious receipts) Islamiyyah, 2/401

**Source:** [ruling on working in banks](http://alifta.com/Fatawa/Fatwaprint.aspx?id=5475&BookID=7&sectionid=) , [Working in Banks](http://www.islamqa.com/en/ref/26771)

Answer (score 4):

According to the Hanafi madh'hab, it is permissible to work in a bank **as long as the job does not entail direct involvement in something *haram*** (e.g. processing interest-based transactions).  So, for example, working as a driver or a guard would be acceptable, since driving and guarding are fundamentally *halal* activities.

**Any money earned therefrom would also be permissible**, as long as it (or a majority thereof) is not derived from *haram* sources.  As Shaykh Muhammad ibn Adam al-Kawthari explains in a related fatwa (emphasis mine):

> [The salary received from the bank is a mixture of unlawful and lawful wealth **of which the majority is lawful**
>   . As such, it would be permissible to accept this money as income
>   provided the actual job is lawful. (See: al-Fatawa al-Hindiyya:
>   5/343).](http://qa.sunnipath.com/issue_view.asp?HD=1&ID=2076&CATE=43)

It still remains preferable to find a job that does not involve such activities, even if the involvement is only by association.

Comment: In an investment bank, wouldn't you expect that most, *if not all*, of the money is derived from haram sources?

Comment: @Daniel There's plenty of halal investments vehicles (e.g. equity, commodity trading).  Unless you know that a clear majority is from riba-based investments, it would still fall under this ruling.

Comment: The hyperlink isn't working

Answer (score 3):

This is the answer according to [Jafari Fiqh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja%27fari_jurisprudence):

ANSWER TO QUESTIONS 3, 4 AND 5:  The following is the translation of
the fatwa of Ayat. Khu'i from "Masa'ilah wa Rudud," p. 112.

Issue no. 319: Is it permissible to work in banks dealing with interest?

RESPONSE:  In His Name, the Exalted.  That is not permissible except
if his work is not primarily linked to riba (interest) transactions
like a sweeper [janitor], guard, driver and similar to them.  And God
knows best.

---

**References:**

- [www.al-islam.org](http://www.al-islam.org/organizations/aalimnetwork/msg00032.html)
- [Current Issues (Islamic Laws of Ayatullah Khoei)](http://www.al-islam.org/laws/al-khui/38.htm)

Comment: Alhamdullillah an other point were sunni and shia' brothers seem to agree!

Answer (score 1):

It’s very simple people make it more complex. 
Just take a simple example, you have a house of your own and someone came to you and asked you to give me your house on rent as I wanted to open a prostitution in your house and i will give you rent for this per month. Now you know the prostitution is a SIN and the purpose is become in your knowledge that your house will be used for prostitution. So will you gave your house to that person on rent? The Answer is NO
Similarly you will not sell your skills to any organization which is clearly supporting BANKS , directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

A riba based investment bank itself is illegal and haram from shariah point of view, so working in it is like helping them in the transgression based on following Quran and hadith:

> “Help you one another in Al‑Birr and At‑Taqwa (virtue, righteousness
>   and piety); but do not help one another in sin and transgression. And
>   fear Allaah. Verily, Allaah is Severe in punishment”
>
> [al-Maa’idah 5:2]
>
> Muslim narrated in his Saheeh (1598) that Jaabir (may Allaah be
>   pleased with him) said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings
>   of Allaah be upon him) cursed the one who consumes riba and the one
>   who pays it, the one who writes it down and the two who witness it,
>   and he said: they are all the same.

Most of the fatwas corroborate this view:

> Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen (may Allaah have mercy on him) was asked: Is it
>   permissible to work in a riba-based company as a driver or guard?
>
> He replied:
>
> It is not permissible to work in riba-based companies even if one is a
>   driver or guard, because his taking a job in a riba-based company
>   implies that he approves of it, and because the one who denounces a
>   thing cannot work in its interests. If he works in its interests then
>   he approves of it, and the one who approves of something that is
>   haraam will have a share of its sin. But if he is directly involved in
>   recording and writing and sending and depositing and so on, then he is
>   undoubtedly involved in something haraam. It is proven in the hadeeth
>   of Jaabir (may Allaah be pleased with him) that the Prophet (peace and
>   blessings of Allaah be upon him) cursed the one who consumes riba and
>   the one who pays it, the one who writes it down and the two who
>   witness it, and he said: they are all the same. End quote from Fataawa
>   Islamiyyah (2/401).

Regarding the money earned from such a bank then [you should  get rid of the money](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/104930) that was given to you, by giving it to the poor and needy and charitable causes without intending any reward from Allah swt and this would also serve as your repentance Inshallah.

Answer (score 0):

In Holy Quran chapter 5 verse 2 it say:

> "...And cooperate in righteousness and piety, but do not cooperate in sin and aggression. And fear Allah ; indeed, Allah is severe in penalty."

It means don't help other people with sinning.

Also the corrupted Christian/Jewish Bible says that interest is a major sin.