# Can I do banking job?

Tags: riba, fatwa

I am a Muslim girl and I have just qualified my Inter examination. When I was in class 2, my father expired and in my family I have 1 younger sister and my mother.

Since then I had been supported by my maternal uncle now I need to find a job which is secure for me being a girl and could not effort large fees for engineering so my choice is to go for banking.

Doing jobs in bank are sin so I want to ask can I do job in bank or not (keeping in mind my problem)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Sharia ruling on working in a bank?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/993/what-is-the-sharia-ruling-on-working-in-a-bank)

Comment: Please have a look at the Q&A link posted above. The answers, when combined, provides different point of views on this matter. In the end, it all comes back to how you perceive your own condition. Steering clear from any sin is still the right way to go. If you can find another job that is clear from anything haram, go for it. May Allah help you.

Answer (score 2):

The answer may be yes and no. In fact apparently your answer would be depend on the part of bank where you intend to work in. I mean in case of working in relevant part jobs of the bank which are relevant to riba acts, then you must avoid it otherwise your income would be haram.

Also you should don't forget that you mustn't find a haram job by justifying yourself that there is no other way for you to afford the matter. Then you must find a halal work or change your fields (if you are looking for halal income and jannah (heaven)).

Answer (score -2):

No sister you can't job in bank its haram because of interest but if there is no interest in the bank than you can and yeah today every bank works on interest but there are also available Islamic banks don't know from where you are but Islamic banks are available in Muslim countries...